# NSSet vs. unordered_set

Tags: c++, objective-c, performance, cocoa, stl

I performed a simple randomized test of the performance of Cocoa's `NSSet` vs. the STL's `unordered_set`. Both are implemented using hash tables. Being that C++ is known for its highly performant code, I was surprised to see that `NSSet` was ~1.5x faster than `unordered_set`. Could anyone shed some light on why this is?

P.S. The test was searching random strings (using `NSString` for `NSSet` and `basic_string<unichar>` for `unordered_set`).

EDIT: Here's the code: https://github.com/fumoboy007/StringCollectionSpeedTest.

Comment: «C++ is known for its highly performant code»... Well, maybe we don't have the same way of quantifying performance...

Comment: So how do you quantify performance? Don't leave me hanging!

Comment: Note that NSSet is "toll-free bridged" to CFSet, and that is open source: http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFSet.c, so you can compare the implementations if you like.

Comment: My suspicion: `std::string` is mutable, `NSString` is immutable, so the hashing of `NSString` is `O(1)` (except for the first time it's hashed), whereas `std::string` may needed to be re-hashed in `O(n)` each time it's used. Another difference is that C++ collectoins use copying, whereas Cocoa collections don't generally copy, only retain.

Comment: @MartinR I was hoping that someone had already done that and could just tell me plain and simply. =)

Comment: @H2CO3 I switched to `NSMutableString` and it gives the same results. Copying is a valid point for insertion, but what about search?

Comment: @fumoboy007 Well, does the C++ stdlib search method accept an object or a reference?

Comment: @fumoboy007 cppreference.com says it takes a `const T &`. Then it's not copying when performing search.

Comment: @fumoboy007 Well one thing that strikes me is that in the C++ test, you are generating the `basic_string`s on the fly. That's slow!

Comment: Also, which C++ library are you using? GNU or LLVM? Try with both...

Comment: @H2CO3 I generate it on the fly but I don't time that part.

Comment: @Macmade LLVM. I'll try GNU now.

Comment: @fumoboy007 Well, you are. `[wordList enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *word, BOOL *stop) { basic_string<unichar> cppWord = [word cppString]; // then insert }`, after this: `cout << "unordered_set insert: " << (double)cppSetInsertElapsedTime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl << endl;`...

Comment: @H2CO3 Notice `cppWord` instantiation is not between `startTime = clock();` and `endTime = clock();`. =P

Comment: @fumoboy007 Ah, yes. Well... I just noticed how you are measuring the time, in fact. That ain't too precise, to be honest!

Comment: @Macmade Okay… Xcode comes with GCC 4.2.1, which doesn't have C++11 support and I'm too lazy to build my own version of GCC, so… no testing with libstdc++ =P

Comment: @H2CO3 It should give a good enough ballpark estimate. =P How else can you do it though?

Comment: @fumoboy007 Pre-instantiate all the `NSString`s and `basic_strings`. Store them in a raw C array (I know, a terrible idea otherwise, but we have to ensure they have the same access speed). Then you create four tight loops (`(insertion and search) x (NSString and basic_string)`), and you start and stop the clock **outside** the loops.

Comment: @H2CO3 Actually, you just gave me a better idea! Start and stop the clock **inside** the loops and accumulate the elapsed times, so that the enumeration is not a factor. I'm doing this already for insert, but not for the search test.

Comment: You certainly didn't enable optimizations. If you did, the compiler had optimized away the *complete* loop for accessing the unordered_set. So basically, your test is flawed.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Verry good. =) I thought I had switched it to release mode… but I hadn't. Now `unordered_set` is ~1.5x faster than `NSSet`. (I don't know if something's being optimized away though.)

Comment: Well it did optimize away the loop on my computer, using the Xcode version which I can't mention. The optimization was as you set it (fast, smallest [-Os]).  Tip: when having template code (e.g. std containers), it is often better to use "fastest" [O3], both regarding code size and speed - instead of "fast, smallest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable optimization and enjoy how "fast" C++ containers are: zero nano seconds for the loop, that has been optimized away by the compiler! Didn't you here it mumbling:  "Don't mess with me!" Compilers are smarter than you think. ;)

So, first trick the compiler: Restructure your test, so that a *result* will be generated by the loop, and that result MUST depend on the actions in each iteration (for example sum the count). That result must be used as well somewhere, for example print it to the console. Otherwise the compiler will again detect that you don't need that result and thus, don't need to perform the loop at all.

Edit:

Test Results (on my system):

It turned out that NSSet and std::unordered_set are about equal in the time for a lookup.

Comment: Is it enough to move the `startTime = clock();` and `endTime = clock();` into the loop (but not use the result of `cppSet.count(string)`)? It seems to be giving me correct results.

Comment: @fumoboy007 Yeah, it is… just tried it with those statements outside the loop and I got "1.84467e+13 seconds". (I like talking to myself.)

Comment: @fumoboy007 Actually, nvm hmmm… I need to investigate further.

Comment: When measuring such bench marks, you should probably use `mach_absolute_time()` for better precision, and run a number of tests (say 20 to 100), where you take the minimum. You can also use std::chrono with the high resolution clock to measure time. The optimal duration for one benchmark test shall be smaller than 10 ms and larger than 1000 ns.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys! (I actually know about `mach_absolute_time()` but was too lazy… =S. Alternatively, you can use `CACurrentMediaTime()`.)